# Krull dimension of $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ is $\leq n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $R$ be the polynomial ring $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$.

$\mathbf{Problem}$: Show that any nonzero prime ideal of $R$ contains an element $f$ such that $R(f)$ is transcendental over $R$ with transcendence degree $1$.  Use induction to show that the Krull dimension of R is at most $n$.

First of all, I'm confused if there is a typo and it should say "$k(f)$ is transcendental over $k$".  In any case, the most I've got towards a solution is observing that any nonzero element of a prime ideal of $R$ generates an extenstion of $k$ of transcendence degree $1$, but that doesn't seem very helpful for the induction.

EDIT: It is a typo, it should be $k$ instead of $R$. The whole point of this exercise is to reduce to the case where the algebra is a polynomial ring.  But it seems like to do the induction you need to pass to a quotient which might not be a polynomial ring.

Comment: Should not this use just krull altitude theorem minimal prime above for non-zero divisor $f$ has height 1 for domain and noether normalization theorem? I assumed you use induction.

Comment: Any element of $k$ will not generate an ideal. Take any $P\in Spec(R)-\{0\}$. From krull altitude theorem converse statement, you know $P$ minimal over a non $k$ element say $f$.($P$ cannot be minimal over an element of $k$ as $P$ will be $R$.) So $k(f)/k$ is degree 1 transcendental extension. You know transcendental degree is $n$ for $R$ and additivity. Hence you know $tr(R/k(f))\leq n-1$. This is where you can use induction. Noether normalization against $R/(f)$ is easier but they are in the same spirit.

Comment: So you agree it's a typo?

Comment: Yes. $k(f)/k$ must be degree 1 transcendental extension.

Comment: I don't think the Krull altitude theorem is in this book.  What do you mean by P is minimal over an element?

Comment: $P$ is a minimal prime above a non-zero divisor $f\in R-k$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your second  comment, but it's not clear to me how your induction works.  If you think you have the right idea, could you post an answer?

Comment: Are suggesting I do the induction on the transcendence degree of the  polynomial ring, i.e., n?

Comment: The only way I see to use induction is with some kind of quotient argument, but how that would work with a polynomial ring is obscure to me.

Comment: Consider $R/(f)$ which is f.g. $k-$algebra. Noether normalization gives the prescription that you can transform variable of $f$ s.t. the transformed $f$ is monic in one of the variable. This allows you to say $R/(f)$ has transcendence degree at most $n-1$ and this has prime ideal height at most $n-1$. Then you can glue the chain to obtain a chain of maximal ideals by adjusting the chain of prime ideal containing $f$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by  "you can transform the variable of f s.t. the transformed f is monic in one of the variable".

Comment: You have to look up for noether normalization's proof for positive characteristic. This proof is valid in $0$ characteristic as well. The proof will yield you a monic polynomial $f'$ to conclude the transcendental degree for $R/(f)\cong R'/(f')$ as $k$ algebra.